# Is restricting attributes to class or properties doable?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-2.0, attributes, custom-attributes

I have two custom attributes defined like so:

```
internal class SchemaAttribute : Attribute {
    internal SchemaAttribute(string schema) {
        Schema = schema;
    }

    internal string Schema { get; private set; }
}

internal class AttributeAttribute : Attribute {
    internal AttributeAttribute(string attribute) {
        Attribute = attribute;
    }

    internal string Attribute { get; private set; }
}
```

I would like to restrict the SchemaAttribute to classes, and the AttributeAttribute to properties.

Is this doable?

Comment: If you find my question if good enough to help someone else, please upvote. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [AttributeUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9(VS.71).aspx) and [AttributeTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx).

It'll look something like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
internal class SchemaAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Implementation
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
internal class AttributeAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: +1. `AttributeTargets` not `AttributeTarget`, I cannot fix your post because SO requires you make at least 6 typos per answer :-(

Answer (score 4):

Look at [AttributeTargetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.aspx)

```
[AttributeTarget(AttributeTargets.Class)]
internal class SchemaAttribute : Attribute
...

[AttributeTarget(AttributeTargets.Property)]
internal class AttributeAttribute: Attribute
...
```